# Optimizing a bit manipulation formula

Tags: c++, performance

I previously posted this question in Stack Overflow, but I was told to post it here as my code is already working and I'm just trying to optimize it. Background: I'm developing a Game Boy emulator, and because most of it is done, I'm currently trying to optimize everything as much as I can.

There's this operation the graphics processor does where it fetches 16 bits worth of graphics data (which encode a row of 8, 2bpp color pixels) to push into a queue.

The data is arranged in a low and high byte pattern, given a position, we mask and shift the corresponding bit in the low and high bytes equally to form a 2 bit number that represents a shade or color. (we also need to shift the high byte's corresponding bit left by 1 to make it the MSB)

The operation visually looks something like this:

```
Given high = 0xff, low = 0x00
Let position = 0
high, low = 0b11111111 0b00000000
              ^          ^
              +----------+-> n = 0b10
              1          0

Let position = 1
high, low = 0b11111111 0b00000000
               ^          ^
               +----------+-> n = 0b10
               1          0
...
```

And the actual binary manip operation might look something like this

```
n = ((low >> (7 - position)) & 1) | (((high >> (7 - position)) & 1) << 1)
```

Other than calculating `(7 - position)` once and storing it in a variable, there's not much room left for optimization.

I was wondering if there's some compiler intrinsic I could use, or if there's a more optimized way of doing this I'm not identifying. Take into account that the high and low bytes don't necessarily have to be in separate variables, they could just be a single 16-bit integer, I've seen similar operations in assembly/intrinsics such as `blend`, or packed integer operations.

Anyways, thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. The name code review is important, to optimize code we need to see the actual code. This question is off-topic on `Code Review` as well as `Stack Overflow` without the actual code to be reviewed. I sorry, but one line of hypothetical code doesn't give us anywhere near enough code to help you. If you could supply 3 or 4 functions or an entire class we might be able to help you optimize the code. Have you profiled the code to see where you are spending the most amount of time?

Comment: @pacmaninbw "to optimize code we need to see the actual code". We have a line of actual code?! Additionally the length of code is not a determiner for if something is on or off topic. [1](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/364) [2](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/466) [3](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1588) [4](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6649) The question would be better with more code, yes. But the question isn't off-topic, unless you've found some AoC rule I've never seen before.

Comment: ([interleave bits](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableObvious)?) `fetches 16 bits worth of graphics data (which encode a row of 8, 2bpp color pixels) to push into a queue` I'd like to see where this data comes from, and where it goes to - source code welcome. What is the requirement: Some bit pattern deep down in the bowels of the machine? Appropriate output from a colour table?

Comment: When we have a description that says "_might look something like this_", there's an implication that we're not looking at the real code.  What would be better would be to show a complete function; that would give a lot more context (the types of all the variables, for a start, and the accompanying comments).  A _great_ question would also include the unit tests and the benchmark code.  I'm pretty sure it would be possible to add the extra information without invalidating Emily's existing answer, and it would rescue this interesting problem from the risk of deletion.

Comment: Missing information (that we might know with more context): what's the access pattern for this function?  Are we computing all eight results from the same byte pair before moving on to the next, or are we accessing the pairs in more random sequence?

Comment: I used the phrase "Might look something like this" to imply that there might not be a single algorithm for this, nor my one is be the best, but that code there is pulled straight from my PPU code. (see [link](https://github.com/Lycoder/Geebly/blob/9a1bab06b586861337468eb9ecc31834ad099585/src/devices/ppu/fifo.hpp#L89))
Also, I don't think sharing documentation is "on-topic", as it would make this question more like homework other than a concrete question about an **specific** formula. Anyways, here's some info: [link](https://www.huderlem.com/demos/gameboy2bpp.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of this question being closed as off topic, I find this problem interesting and will hazard an answer.

I believe that the best answer here is simply a lookup table. You only have 16 bits of input domain, so you could make a LUT with 2^16 entries, each entry giving the 8 colours as output. This will cost you around 64-512 KByte of memory depending on how you encode the output. For an emulator this seems affordable even on low end systems. I would expect this to be at least 8 times faster than your code because you're getting all colours in parallel + you're not doing a  bunch of bit arithmetic so I wouldn't be surprised if this was even faster than that. Ideally you've baked your active palette into the LUT (or prebaked LUTs for all palettes) so that the LUT provides direct RGB tuples that you can blit onto the screen without further massaging.

If half a meg of RAM is too much (I don't know what you're running this on), you can swizzle the nibbles around so that you have the first byte with the first 4 pixels and the second byte with the last two pixels (e.g. turn 0xABCD into 0xAC, 0xBD). Then you can use a 256 entry LUT with 4 colour as output and run each swizzled byte through it separately. Conceivably this LUT would cost between 256 bytes or 1KB depending again on how you encode the output. Even with the swizzle, this should be faster than your original code as you're getting all the colours in parallel.

Swizzle is relatively cheap:

```
Given two bytes A, B

X = (A & 0xF0) | ((B & 0xF0) >> 4)
Y = ((A & 0x0F) << 4) | (B & 0x0F)
```

Note that even though you're still doing some binary ops, you're getting several pixels in parallel through the LUT.